# Подключение базы данных MS SQL к проекту Django

Tags: python, django, sql-server

Разворачиваю проект на Django(версия 3.0), задача подключить к нему базу на ms sql. Я не знаю как можно и на каких версиях подключить базу в setting.py перепробовал уже много(django-mssql, django-pyodbc-azure и pyodbc - но последний вариант не подходит). Если я использую pyodbc, то теряю возможность применять модели. Подскажите какие версии и каких библиотек необходимы. Уже думаю о downgrade до django 1.8, но даже на нем в тестовом варианте еще не нашел работающих либ и настроек к ним.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-mssql-backend/ а эту либу пробовали?

Comment: нет, но пишут что это одна из веток azure. боюсь что не получится ничего, тяжеловато django дружит с не дефолтными базами

Comment: ага только либа django-pyodbc-azure не поддерживает django 3 сюдя по оф докам в отличии от той что я скинул

Comment: Ок я попробую, тогда еще вопрос(возможно глупый), у всех этих библиотек в процессе использования говорится лишь об инсталляции, в setting.py указывается движок sql_server.pyodbc, мне любопытно как джанго определяет какую либу использовать?

Comment: ну так все правильно, они же подходят только для mssql, вот и указн движок sql сервер параметр в `settings` `ENGINE` и указывает какой движок брать, по дефолту sqllite  `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'`,а если о том какой драйвер для mssql использовать то надо указать в `drivers` например `'OPTIONS': { 'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', },`